# Handling exceptions in an iteratee library without an error state

Tags: scala, haskell, io, scalaz, loops

I'm trying to write an enumerator for reading files line by line from a `java.io.BufferedReader` using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) 7's iteratee library, which currently only provides an (extremely slow) enumerator for `java.io.Reader`.

The problems I'm running into are related to the fact that all of the other iteratee libraries I've used (e.g. [Play 2.0's](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Iteratees) and [John Millikin's `enumerator`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/enumerator) for Haskell) have had an error state as one of their `Step` type's constructors, and Scalaz 7 doesn't.

### My current implementation

Here's what I currently have. First for some imports and `IO` wrappers:

```
import java.io.{ BufferedReader, File, FileReader }
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect.IO, iteratee.{ Iteratee => I, _ }

def openFile(f: File) = IO(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)))
def readLine(r: BufferedReader) = IO(Option(r.readLine))
def closeReader(r: BufferedReader) = IO(r.close())
```

And an type alias to clean things up a bit:

```
type ErrorOr[A] = Either[Throwable, A]
```

And now a `tryIO` helper, modeled (loosely, and probably wrongly) on the one in `enumerator`:

```
def tryIO[A, B](action: IO[B]) = I.iterateeT[A, IO, ErrorOr[B]](
  action.catchLeft.map(
    r => I.sdone(r, r.fold(_ => I.eofInput, _ => I.emptyInput))
  )
)
```

An enumerator for the `BufferedReader` itself:

```
def enumBuffered(r: => BufferedReader) = new EnumeratorT[ErrorOr[String], IO] {
  lazy val reader = r
  def apply[A] = (s: StepT[ErrorOr[String], IO, A]) => s.mapCont(k =>
    tryIO(readLine(reader)) flatMap {
      case Right(None)       => s.pointI
      case Right(Some(line)) => k(I.elInput(Right(line))) >>== apply[A]
      case Left(e)           => k(I.elInput(Left(e)))
    }
  )
}
```

And finally an enumerator that's responsible for opening and closing the reader:

```
def enumFile(f: File) = new EnumeratorT[ErrorOr[String], IO] {
  def apply[A] = (s: StepT[ErrorOr[String], IO, A]) => s.mapCont(k =>
    tryIO(openFile(f)) flatMap {
      case Right(reader) => I.iterateeT(
        enumBuffered(reader).apply(s).value.ensuring(closeReader(reader))
      )
      case Left(e) => k(I.elInput(Left(e)))
    }
  )
}
```

Now suppose for example that I want to collect all the lines in a file that contain at least twenty-five `'0'` characters into a list. I can write:

```
val action: IO[ErrorOr[List[String]]] = (
  I.consume[ErrorOr[String], IO, List] %=
  I.filter(_.fold(_ => true, _.count(_ == '0') >= 25)) &=
  enumFile(new File("big.txt"))
).run.map(_.sequence)
```

In many ways this seems to work beautifully: I can kick the action off with `unsafePerformIO` and it will chunk through tens of millions of lines and gigabytes of data in a couple of minutes, in constant memory and without blowing the stack, and then close the reader when it's done. If I give it the name of a file that doesn't exist, it will dutifully give me back the exception wrapped in a `Left`, and `enumBuffered` at least seems to behave appropriately if it hits an exception while reading.

### Potential problems

I have some concerns about my implementation, though—particularly of `tryIO`. For example, suppose I try to compose a few iteratees:

```
val it = for {
  _ <- tryIO[Unit, Unit](IO(println("a")))
  _ <- tryIO[Unit, Unit](IO(throw new Exception("!")))
  r <- tryIO[Unit, Unit](IO(println("b")))
} yield r
```

If I run this, I get the following:

```
scala> it.run.unsafePerformIO()
a
b
res11: ErrorOr[Unit] = Right(())
```

If I try the same thing with `enumerator` in GHCi, the result is more like what I'd expect:

```
...> run $ tryIO (putStrLn "a") >> tryIO (error "!") >> tryIO (putStrLn "b")
a
Left !
```

I just don't see a way to get this behavior without an error state in the iteratee library itself.

### My questions

I don't claim to be any kind of expert on iteratees, but I have used the various Haskell implementations in a few projects, feel like I more or less understand the fundamental concepts, and had coffee with Oleg once. I'm at a loss here, though. Is this a reasonable way to handle exceptions in the absence of an error state? Is there a way to implement `tryIO` that would behave more like the `enumerator` version? Is there some kind of time bomb waiting for me in the fact that my implementation behaves differently?

Comment: I won't have a good answer for you anyway, but I'm curious: what are your performance and/or abstraction goals?  Presumably you care some about performance, or `Reader` would be fine; and presumably you care some about abstraction, or you'd bail on this overhead and use much more compact and probably better-performing strategies (for cases which are simple and do not need to compose).  For example, `Try(closing(io.Source.fromFile("big.txt")){_.getLines.filter(_.count(_=='0') >= 25)}.toList)`, with the obvious three-line definition for `closing`.

Comment: @RexKerr: The performance of the `Reader` enumerator that comes with Scalaz is incredibly bad—literally dozens of times worse than the enumerator I've implemented here. But I'm happy to take a reasonable performance hit for the convenience of being able for example to `flatMap(enumFile)` a enumerator that lists the files in a directory and get an enumerator of the lines of all those files, without ever having to worry about explicitly closing any resources (which the iteratee approach allows).

Comment: If you can provide a fully working gist with your current example, I can try and convert it to what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @IvanMeredith: Thanks! Here's [the gist](https://gist.github.com/4090746), which I've tested against the current head of the `scalaz-seven` branch.

Comment: For the record here's [my solution](https://gist.github.com/4091180).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT here is the real solution. I left in the original post because I think its worthwhile seeing the pattern. What works for Klesli works for IterateeT

```
import java.io.{ BufferedReader, File, FileReader }
import scalaz._, Scalaz._, effect._, iteratee.{ Iteratee => I, _ }

object IterateeIOExample {
  type ErrorOr[+A] = EitherT[IO, Throwable, A]

  def openFile(f: File) = IO(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)))
  def readLine(r: BufferedReader) = IO(Option(r.readLine))
  def closeReader(r: BufferedReader) = IO(r.close())

  def tryIO[A, B](action: IO[B]) = I.iterateeT[A, ErrorOr, B] {
    EitherT.fromEither(action.catchLeft).map(r => I.sdone(r, I.emptyInput))
  }

  def enumBuffered(r: => BufferedReader) = new EnumeratorT[String, ErrorOr] {
    lazy val reader = r
    def apply[A] = (s: StepT[String, ErrorOr, A]) => s.mapCont(k =>
      tryIO(readLine(reader)) flatMap {
        case None => s.pointI
        case Some(line) => k(I.elInput(line)) >>== apply[A]
      })
  }

  def enumFile(f: File) = new EnumeratorT[String, ErrorOr] {
    def apply[A] = (s: StepT[String, ErrorOr, A]) => 
      tryIO(openFile(f)).flatMap(reader => I.iterateeT[String, ErrorOr, A](
        EitherT(
          enumBuffered(reader).apply(s).value.run.ensuring(closeReader(reader)))))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val action = (
      I.consume[String, ErrorOr, List] %=
      I.filter(a => a.count(_ == '0') >= 25) &=
      enumFile(new File(args(0)))).run.run

    println(action.unsafePerformIO().map(_.size))
  }
}
```

===== Original Post =====

I feel like you need an EitherT in the mix. Without EitherT you are just ending up with a 3 Lefts or Rights. With EitherT it would propergate the left.

I think what you really want is

```
type ErrorOr[+A] = EitherT[IO, Throwable, A] 
I.iterateeT[A, ErrorOr, B]
```

The following code mimics how you are currently composing things. Because IterateeT has no concept of left and right, when you compose it, you just end up with a bunch of IO/Id's.

```
scala> Kleisli((a:Int) => 4.right[String].point[Id])
res11: scalaz.Kleisli[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,Int,scalaz.\/[String,Int]] = scalaz.KleisliFunctions$$anon$18@73e771ca

scala> Kleisli((a:Int) => "aa".left[Int].point[Id])
res12: scalaz.Kleisli[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,Int,scalaz.\/[String,Int]] = scalaz.KleisliFunctions$$anon$18@be41b41

scala> for { a <- res11; b <- res12 } yield (a,b)
res15: scalaz.Kleisli[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,Int,(scalaz.\/[String,Int], scalaz.\/[String,Int])] = scalaz.KleisliFunctions$$anon$18@42fd1445

scala> res15.run(1)
res16: (scalaz.\/[String,Int], scalaz.\/[String,Int]) = (\/-(4),-\/(aa))
```

In the following code, instead of using Id, we use an EitherT. Since EitherT has the same bind behaviour as Either, we end up with what we want.

```
scala>  type ErrorOr[+A] = EitherT[Id, String, A]
defined type alias ErrorOr

scala> Kleisli[ErrorOr, Int, Int]((a:Int) => EitherT(4.right[String].point[Id]))
res22: scalaz.Kleisli[ErrorOr,Int,Int] = scalaz.KleisliFunctions$$anon$18@58b547a0

scala> Kleisli[ErrorOr, Int, Int]((a:Int) => EitherT("aa".left[Int].point[Id]))
res24: scalaz.Kleisli[ErrorOr,Int,Int] = scalaz.KleisliFunctions$$anon$18@342f2ceb

scala> for { a <- res22; b <- res24 } yield 2
res25: scalaz.Kleisli[ErrorOr,Int,Int] = scalaz.KleisliFunctions$$anon$18@204eab31

scala> res25.run(2).run
res26: scalaz.Scalaz.Id[scalaz.\/[String,Int]] = -\/(aa)
```

You can replace Keisli with IterateeT and Id with IO to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks—I played briefly with using `EitherT` here this morning and couldn't get the types to work out, but I'm trying again now.

Comment: I'm converting types now too.

Answer (score 4):

The way `pipes` does it is to type-class composition using the `Channel` type class:

```hs
class Channel p where
    {-| 'idT' acts like a \'T\'ransparent proxy, passing all requests further
        upstream, and passing all responses further downstream. -}
    idT :: (Monad m) => a' -> p a' a a' a m r

    {-| Compose two proxies, satisfying all requests from downstream with
        responses from upstream. -}
    (>->) :: (Monad m)
          => (b' -> p a' a b' b m r)
          -> (c' -> p b' b c' c m r)
          -> (c' -> p a' a c' c m r)
    p1 >-> p2 = p2 <-< p1
```

... and derived a lifted composition over `EitherT` from the base composition.  This is a special case of the the principle of proxy transformers, introduced in `pipes-2.4`, that allows lifting composition over arbitrary extensions.

This lifting requires defining an `EitherT` specialized to the shape of the `Proxy` type in `Control.Proxy.Trans.Either`:

```hs
newtype EitherP e p a' a b' b (m :: * -> *) r
  = EitherP { runEitherP :: p a' a b' b m (Either e r) }
```

This specialization to the `Proxy` shape is necessary in order to be able to define a well-typed instance of the `Channel` class.  Scala might be more flexible in this regard than Haskell.

Then I just redefine the `Monad` instance (and other instances) along with all the ordinary `EitherT` operations for this specialized type:

```hs
throw :: (Monad (p a' a b' b m)) => e -> EitherP e p a' a b' b m r
throw = EitherP . return . Left

catch
 :: (Monad (p a' a b' b m))
 => EitherP e p a' a b' b m r        -- ^ Original computation
 -> (e -> EitherP f p a' a b' b m r) -- ^ Handler
 -> EitherP f p a' a b' b m r        -- ^ Handled computation
catch m f = EitherP $ do
    e <- runEitherP m
    runEitherP $ case e of
        Left  l -> f     l
        Right r -> right r
```

With this in hand I can then define the following lifted composition instance:

```hs
-- Given that 'p' is composable, so is 'EitherP e p'
instance (Channel p) => Channel (EitherP e p) where
    idT = EitherP . idT
    p1 >-> p2 = (EitherP .) $ runEitherP . p1 >-> runEitherP . p2
```

To understand what is going on there, just follow the types:

```hs
p1 :: b' -> EitherP e p a' a b' b m r
p2 :: c' -> EitherP e p b' b c' c m r

runEitherP . p1 :: b' -> p a' a b' b m (Either e r)
runEitherP . p2 :: c' -> p b' b c' c m (Either e r)

-- Use the base composition for 'p'
runEitherP . p1 >-> runEitherP . p2
 :: c' -> p a' a c' c m (Either e r)

-- Rewrap in EitherP
(EitherP . ) $ runEitherP . p1 >-> runEitherP . p2
 :: c' -> EitherP e p a' a c' c m r
```

This lets you throw and catch errors within a particular stage without interrupting other stages.  Here's an example I've copied and pasted from my `pipes-2.4` announcement post:

```hs
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.Either as E
import Safe (readMay)

promptInts :: () -> EitherP String Proxy C () () Int IO r
promptInts () = recover $ forever $ do
    str <- lift getLine
    case readMay str of
        Nothing -> E.throw "Could not parse an integer"
        Just n  -> liftP $ respond n

recover p =
    p `E.catch` (\str -> lift (putStrLn str) >> recover p)

main = runProxy $ runEitherK $ mapP printD <-< promptInts
```

Here's the result:

```hs
>>> main
1<Enter>
1
Test<Enter>
Could not parse an integer
Apple<Enter>
Could not parse an integer
5<Enter>
5
```

The answer to the iteratee approach is similar.  You must take your existing way of composing iteratees and lift it over `EitherT`.  Whether or not you use type-classes or just define a new composition operator is up to you.

Some other useful links:

- [`pipes-2.4` announcement post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/10/pipes-24-proxy-transformers-extra.html)
- [`Control.Proxy.Class`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/2.5.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Class.html), [`Control.Proxy.Trans`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/2.5.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Trans.html), and [`Control.Proxy.Trans.Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/2.5.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Trans-Either.html)
- A [very similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402892/what-approach-to-error-handling-to-use-with-pipes-core/11417819#11417819) on the same subject (except for `pipes)