# Error handling in pipes

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

### Backstory

I have a number of data files, each of them containing a list of data records (one per line). 
Similar to CSV but sufficiently different that I'd prefer to write my own parser rather than using a CSV library.
For the purpose of this question I will use a simplified data file that contains just one number per line:

```
1
2
3
error
4
```

As you can see it is possible that a file contains malformed data in which case the whole file should be considered malformed.

The kind of data-processing I want to do can be expressed in terms of maps and folds.
So, I thought this would be a good opportunity to learn how to use the `pipes` library.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import           Control.Monad.Except
import           Pipes ((>->))
import qualified Pipes as P
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified Pipes.Safe as P
import qualified System.IO as IO
```

First, I create a producer of lines in the text file.
This is very similar to the example in the docs of `Pipes.Safe`.

```
getLines = do
    P.bracket (IO.openFile "data.txt" IO.ReadMode) IO.hClose P.fromHandle
```

Next, I need a function to parse each of these lines.
As I mentioned before, this might fail, which I will represent with `Either`.

```
type ErrMsg = String

parseNumber :: String -> Either ErrMsg Integer
parseNumber s = case reads s of
                  [(n, "")] -> Right n
                  _         -> Left $ "Parse Error: \"" ++ s ++ "\""
```

For simplicity, as a first step, I want to collect all data records into a list of records.
The most straight-forward approach is to pipe all the lines through the parser and just collect the whole thing into a list.

```
readNumbers1 :: IO [Either ErrMsg Integer]
readNumbers1 = P.runSafeT $ P.toListM $
    getLines >-> P.map parseNumber
```

Unfortunately, that creates a list of eithers of records.
However, if the file contains one wrong record then the whole file should be considered wrong.
What I really want is an either of a list of records.
Of course I can just use `sequence` to *transpose* the list of eithers.

```
readNumbers2 :: IO (Either ErrMsg [Integer])
readNumbers2 = sequence <$> readNumbers1
```

But, that would read the whole file even if the first line is already malformed.
These files can be large and I have many of them, so, it would be better if the reading would stop at the first error.

### Question

**My Question** is how to achieve that.
How to abort parsing upon the first malformed record?

### What I got so far

My first thought was to use the monad instance of `Either ErrMsg` and `P.mapM` instead of `P.map`.
Since we are reading from a file we already have `IO` and `SafeT` in our monad stack, so, I guess I'll need `ExceptT` to get error handling into that monad stack.
This is the point where I'm stuck.
I tried many different combinations and always ended up being yelled at by the type-checker.
The following is the closest I can get to *it compiles*.

```
readNumbers3 = P.runSafeT $ runExceptT $ P.toListM $
    getLines >-> P.mapM (ExceptT . return . parseNumber)
```

The infered type of `readNumbers3` reads

```
*Main> :t readNumbers3
readNumbers3
  :: (MonadIO m, P.MonadSafe (ExceptT ErrMsg (P.SafeT m)),
      P.MonadMask m, P.Base (ExceptT ErrMsg (P.SafeT m)) ~ IO) =>
     m (Either ErrMsg [Integer])
```

which looks close to what I want:

```
readNumbers3 :: IO (Either ErrMsg [Integer])
```

However, as soon as I try to actually execute that action I get the following error message in ghci:

```
*Main> readNumbers3

<interactive>:7:1:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO’
                with actual type ‘P.Base (ExceptT ErrMsg (P.SafeT m0))’
    The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

If I try to apply the following type-signature:

```
readNumbers3 :: IO (Either ErrMsg [Integer])
```

Then I get the following error message:

```
error.hs:108:5:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO’
                with actual type ‘P.Base (ExceptT ErrMsg (P.SafeT IO))’
    In the first argument of ‘(>->)’, namely ‘getLines’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘getLines >-> P.mapM (ExceptT . return . parseNumber)’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘P.toListM $ getLines >-> P.mapM (ExceptT . return . parseNumber)’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

### Aside

Another motivation for moving the error handling into the pipe's base monad is that it would make further data processing much easier if I wouldn't have to juggle with eithers in my maps and folds.

Comment: Here's a start at an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11417819/866915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an incremental approach to solving the problem.

Following Tekmo's suggestion in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11417819/866915)
we aim to operate in the following monad:

```
ExceptT String (Pipe a b m) r
```

We begin with imports and the definition of `parseNumber`:

```
import           Control.Monad.Except
import           Pipes ((>->))
import qualified Pipes as P
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

parseNumber :: String -> Either String Integer
parseNumber s = case reads s of
                  [(n, "")] -> Right n
                  _         -> Left $ "Parse Error: \"" ++ s ++ "\""
```

Here is a plain Producer of Strings in the IO-monad we'll use as our input:

```
p1 :: P.Producer String IO ()
p1 = P.stdinLn >-> P.takeWhile (/= "quit")
```

To lift it to the ExceptT monad we just use `lift`:

```
p2 :: ExceptT String (P.Producer String IO) ()
p2 = lift p1
```

Here is a pipeline segment which converts Strings to Integers in the ExceptT monad:

```
p4 :: ExceptT String (P.Pipe String Integer IO) a
p4 = forever $ 
       do s <- lift P.await
          case parseNumber s of
            Left e  -> throwError e
            Right n -> lift $ P.yield n
```

The probably can be written more combinatorially, but I've left it very explicit for clarity.

Next we join p2 and p4 together. The result is also in the ExceptT monad.

```
-- join together p2 and p4
p7 :: ExceptT String (P.Producer Integer IO) ()
p7 = ExceptT $ runExceptT p2 >-> runExceptT p4
```

Tekmo's SO answer suggests creating a new operator for this.

Finally, we can use `toListM'` to run this pipeline. (I've included the definition of `toListM'` here because it doesn't appear in my installed version of Pipes.Prelude)

```
p8 :: IO ([Integer], Either String ())
p8 = toListM' $ runExceptT p7

toListM' :: Monad m => P.Producer a m r -> m ([a], r)
toListM' = P.fold' step begin done
  where
    step x a = x . (a:)
    begin = id
    done x = x []
```

Examples of how p8 works:

```
ghci> p8
4
5
6
quit
([4,5,6],Right ())

ghci> p8
5
asd
([5],Left "Parse Error: \"asd\"")
```

**Update**

You can simplify the code by generalizing `parseNumber` like this:

```
parseNumber' :: (MonadError [Char] m) => String -> m Integer
parseNumber' s = case reads s of
                   [(n, "")] -> return n
                   _         -> throwError $ "Parse Error: \"" ++ s ++ "\""
```

Then `p4` may be written:

```
p4' :: ExceptT String (P.Pipe String Integer IO) a
p4' = forever $ lift P.await >>= parseNumber' >>= lift . P.yield
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. That solved my problem. I generalized `p4'` as `mapE` over any arbitrary function in `MonadError e`. Defining the following operator can make the syntax even terser: `infixl 6 ^>?>`
`p1 ^>?> p2 = lift p1 >?> p2`