# Wrapping conduit in ExceptT

Tags: haskell, conduit

What is a good way to wrap a conduit in `ExceptT`? The approach should stop the processing when there is an error, and extract the error message. Here is a toy code without error-handling - it just silently stops:

```
import Data.Conduit as C
import Data.ByteString as BS
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Text as T

-- just a dummy processing to simulate errors
process :: BS.ByteString -> Either (Int,T.Text) BS.ByteString
process inp = if (BS.null inp) then Left $ (1,"Empty input") else Right inp

-- silent processing - stops on error but doesn't tell us what it is
sink :: MonadIO m => Consumer BS.ByteString m ()
sink = do
       bs <- await
       case bs of
        Just val -> do
            let msg = process val
            case msg of  
              Left _ -> return ()
              Right x -> (liftIO $ return x) >> sink
        Nothing -> return ()
```

How could we change the type signature of `sink` to something like below?

```
sink :: MonadIO m => ExceptT e m (Consumer BS.ByteString m ())
```

In case of `Left`, it will be nice to break out of the pipeline, and return the error message to top.
I read this [blog post](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2012-07-24-in-praise-of-EitherT.html) but haven't understood it well enough yet to apply it to conduit (which also has complicated type signature). I will like to apply the proposed approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11417819/986475) to conduit - it seems `EitherT` suggested in the approach has now been subsumed by `ExceptT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful signature to remember is:

```
ExceptT :: m (Either e b)  ->  ExceptT e m b
```

and with that in mind, this code type checks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

import Data.Conduit as C
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Text as T

-- just a dummy processing to simulate errors
process :: BS.ByteString -> Either (Int,T.Text) BS.ByteString
process inp = if (BS.null inp) then Left $ (1,"Empty input") else Right inp

type Err = (Int,T.Text)

sink' :: MonadIO m => ExceptT Err (ConduitM ByteString Int m) ()
sink' = do  bs <- lift await
            case bs of
              Just inp -> do
                msg <- ExceptT (return $ process inp)   -- ***
                lift $ yield (BS.length msg)
                liftIO $ BS.putStrLn msg
                sink'
              Nothing -> return ()
```

This isn't exactly a sink, but it should illustrate how to do things.

The typing on line (***) goes like this:

```
process inp             :: Either Err ByteString
                            -- (a pure value)
return (process inp)    :: m (Either Err ByteString)
                            -- here m = ConduitM ByteString Int mIO
ExceptT (...)           :: ExceptT Err m ()
```

So the use of `return` here sets things up so we can apply the `ExceptT` constructor.

Then when you call bind on an `ExceptT ...` value, you trigger the
error checking code that ExceptT provides. Thus, if `inp` was a `Left` an
error will be raised.

**Update**

Here is a version with `Sink`:

```
sink' :: MonadIO m => ExceptT Err (Sink ByteString m) ()
sink' = do  bs <- lift await
            case bs of
              Just inp -> do
                msg <- ExceptT (return $ process inp)
                liftIO $ BS.putStrLn msg
                sink'
              Nothing -> return ()
```

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with exceptT but still can't figure out how to have a signature like `ExceptT Err (Consumer ByteString m ()) ()`. Not sure if that is good way to go either because I am trying to do the error processing at top of pipeline level - something like this ` <some conduit> $$ <some conduit>` which if in `Left` state at any point should stop and return `Left` error. In case of `Pipes`, it is `ExceptT e (Pipe a b m) r` as noted in the post I linked in my question.

Comment: Answer updated with `Sink`. Actually I don't think you can create `ExceptT Err (Consumer ...)` because Consumer is universally qualified over one of its type parameters. `Pipe` is not defined like that - it is closer to `Sink`. So I think `ExceptT ... Sink ...` is what you're looking for

Comment: Yep, I figured the same. Thanks so much for help.